# How to resolve tooltip warning in testcase vue test utils?

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, bootstrap-vue, vue-test-utils

While using v-b-tooltip.hover of bootstrap-vue the unit test keeps giving warnings:
**[BootstrapVue warn]: tooltip - The provided target is no valid HTML element.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution by using **attachTo: createContainer()** while defining componentData. Also have to redefine whenever wrapper is redefined.

```
const createContainer = (tag = "div") => {
  const container = document.createElement(tag);
  document.body.appendChild(container);

  return container;
};

const componentData = {
  attachTo: createContainer(),
  store,
  localVue
};

const wrapper = shallowMount(Index, componentData);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This helped us get rid of those warnings in the test output when using Jest & Vue Test Utils.